# Here API: Show exactly polyline of my route

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to show the polyline of my generated route (multiple route) with here API? In the moment they show only direct lines and not the polyline on the streets. It should look like in googlemaps (exactly route - not only direct lines)

Comment: What platform are you asking for? Android  / iOS / Web ?

Comment: Hi, it is for Android

Comment: @maka1000 Actually the polyline to drawn is totally dependent on the quality of geo locations data you provide it. the more the co-ordinates(accurate!) the more connected and matched with polyline will be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

To solve it, add "representation" parameter to your query, with value of "navigation". Now every "leg" item in your response will contain an array of string named "shape". Use the coordinates from that array, and your route will be exact.

[image]